# Fetch values from different table according to the value of a field

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, case

In my project, I have two types of videos: free videos and featured videos. I am saving the details of free videos in a table *channel_videos* as shown below:

```
id  videotitle    video     thumbnail  added_on
```

And I am saving details of featured videos in a table *video*.

```
videoid    title    videolink    videothumbnail  added_on
```

When a user views a video the watched videos details along with viewed user details will be stored in another table *viewedmovies* .

```
id   user_id   movie_id   videotype    watched_on
```

In this table if the value of field *videotype* is 0 (free video), then query the table *channel_videos*, if the *videotype* is 1 (featured video) then query the table *video*.

```
select viewedmovies.id,viewedmovies.watched_on,video.title,video.videothumbnail,video.views,
video.likes,video.length,video.videoid from viewedmovies INNER JOIN video ON viewedmovies.movie_id=video.videoid
and viewedmovies.user_id=1 group by viewedmovies.user_id,viewedmovies.movie_id,viewedmovies.videotype order by watched_on desc LIMIT 6
```

The above is the query I have used. But this fetches result from video table only.

How can I do this in a single query? Also I want the results to be grouped on movie_id,videotype and user_id fields of *viewedmovies* table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While there's always some SQL magic to get what you want, I think there's a problem with your database structure.


As the information for the free and featured videos is the same, you could make things a lot easier if you just put them in the same table. The only thing you'll have to add is a 'is_free' column.

Answer (score 1):

I havent tested it, but something like this should work:

```
SELECT viewedmovies.id, viewedmovies.watched_on
, video.title, video.videothumbnail, video.views, video.likes, video.length, video.videoid
, channel_videos.videotitle, channel_videos.thumbnail, channel_videos.id
 FROM viewedmovies
 LEFT JOIN video
 ON (viewedmovies.movie_id=video.videoid AND viewedmovies.user_id=1 AND viewedmovies.videotype=1)
 LEFT JOIN channel_videos
 ON (viewedmovies.movie_id=channel_videos.id AND viewedmovies.user_id=1 AND viewedmovies.videotype=0)
 GROUP BY viewedmovies.user_id, viewedmovies.movie_id, viewedmovies.videotype
 ORDER BY watched_on desc
 LIMIT 6
```